# Using a CPU manually

Tags: cpu, wiring, ram, hard-drive

Ok, I know this may sound dumb but, here is the thing:
I recently removed a cpu, ram and hard disk from my 10-ish year old pc. At first, I did that to understand how the pc was built. Now, the next logical step would be to take it further and  rebuild it. But I have no idea how to do that. So here is the simplified question:
How can I *manually* wire a cpu, ram and hard disk *without* using the old motherboard. What would i need? Adaptors, sockets etc?

EDIT: I mean something really simplistic. Like something that executes assembly code only.
As I told in the comments below.

Comment: not gonna happen...

Comment: A PC is much more than a CPU, some RAM and a hard drive. It's all the other things on the motherboard that make it into a PC with screen, keyboard, mouse, network, etc. Building a PC *without* a motherboard is essentially impossible, especially for a beginner.

Comment: I think i should be more clear: My intention is not to build a COMPLETE pc out of scraps. Instead, I was wondering how could I build something that is REALLY simplictic. Like, something that execute assembly instructions only. Is that impossible too ?

Comment: So far, everyone is taking you literally. You may simply not know about hobby-friendly embedded CPUs like MSP430s (TI launchpad, $4.30), Arduino (huge following, but possibly too high level given your current assembly programming goal), PICs, AVR, smaller ARMs, etc. There's a HUGE sliding scale of processor/board complexity from those right up to full class PCs.

Comment: @Matt Young: I don't think that was a good [edit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/64148/revisions#). The OP asked (and accepted) and answer about **building a PC**, now it is only about assembly programming, and does not match any of the answers any more.  The assembly question is very different.

Comment: Just trying to make sense of a random collection of thoughts. It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: If you want to make a computer out of discrete parts (rather than using a system-on-a-chip type microcontroller which already has memory, serial ports, and other things on one chip), use some old processor like a Motorola 68000, in a DIP package that you can plug into a breadboard.  Get [this old book](http://www.amazon.com/Microprocessor-Systems-Design-Hardware-Interfacing/dp/0534948227) and off you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, realistically.

A long time ago, computers had wires visible to the naked eye, or were even hand-assembled; [someone is doing a re-enactment of this](http://www.homebrewcpu.com/).

These days they're held together on a 6-layer PCB which has been carefully routed to ensure that signals can travel at 1GHz without distortion or interference, assembled out of parts that are extremely hard to solder by hand. The support chipset is large and complex; you need all of it to work if you're going to see any results.

If you're seriously interested in building your own, it is possible to build 80s-era technology by hand; see ["Veronica"](http://hackaday.com/tag/veronica/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a little article about this kind of project. And since yours is the best answer yet, have my accept. EDIT: Oh and, here is that article for anyone else interested: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Build-an-8-Bit-Computer/step2/An-Introduction-to-Electronics/

Comment: You shouldn't accept within an hour like that. Someone with a better answer may pass right over an accepted answer question.

Answer (score 2):

The parts of a computer such as those you mentioned cannot be used without an appropriate motherboard.  Anything that could do the job IS a motherboard.  Designing/building one is generally outside the scope of abilities for one person - especially one with no training and experience.

Answer (score 1):

(Your question seems to have been edited, so I might not be answering the same question that the other answerers did.)

Programming in assembly can be done on almost any computer or microcontroller you can get. Of these a PC might be the most readily available, but unfortunately the assembly language of the modern Intel chips is very complex.

An alternative is to buy a RaspebrryPi. It uses an ARM chip, which has IMO one of the most elegant assembly architectures ever designed (in the same league as the PDP11 and the 68k). And you might teach yourself some Linux.

Another path is to buy a development board for a microcontroller. Darron suggested a few in a comment, there are many many more.

Yet another option is to get a simulator that runs on your PC but simulates a processor of your choice.

Comment: I recently got an RPi for pretty much the exact stuff you talk about in your 3rd paragraph. Do you know any good guides/tutorials for that kind of stuff, ie starting the RPi without the linux OS so that you can do bare metal programming in C/asm on it? Maybe after awhile I'll want to put the OS on it...

Comment: I figured out how it can be done, but I did not yet write it down. I'll see if I can find the time to do it. Drop me an email to remind me (wouter monkey voti dot nl)